# iOS first inapp-purchase must submit binary for sandbox testing

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, sandbox

i am working inapp-purchase project and first time for creating inapp-purchase in new app iTunes shows the message in inapp-purchase manage link to shows the message is below

**The first In-App Purchase for an app must be submitted for review at the same time that you submit an app version. You must do this on the Version Details page. Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below.**

like below screen shot:

[image]

**i want to test sandbox environment with test user on device, store kit returns no products available!**

click to view inapp details shows the warning message below screen shot :

[image]

i want to test sandbox (inapppurchase) to device how to do it?

my app not upload binary details and i want to test it!

please......., help with me important...!

Thanks...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to simply upload a binary and then just reject it yourself, that should be enough.

**update 2017** I just saw a downvote on this 5 year old answer. Things have changed a lot since then, especially in the area of (testing) IAP and beta versions. I have not recently been able to verify if this upload&reject step still makes sense.

Comment: @HeroVsZero be patient! You may need to wait for several hours between some steps.

Comment: yes u asking correct i am test next day on sandbox environment is working...!Thanks lot!

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely NO for uploading a binary!!!

It's an urban legend but it's rather dangerous regarding official Apple docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Important: DO NOT upload the development binary to iTunes Connect until the application is ready for App Review approval. If the binary is present in iTunes Connect and it is not fully functional, App Review will review the binary and likely reject the development binary. Testing In-App Purchase will fail if you or App Review reject your most recent binary in iTunes Connect. The workaround in this case is to upload a binary without In-App Purchase features that can get approved by App Review. Once the binary is approved, resume testing the binary with In-App Purchase features.

THE SOLUTION for your issue:
Your problem is that you moved the process one step further than Apple advised and uploaded the picture for the in-app-purchase, so it's in

"Ready to Submit"

state (see your illustration) which is not correct (DO NOT ask why or search for any rational, I killed some hours with it) Your in-app has to be in

"Waiting for Screenshot"

So you have to make a new one with different name - even if you delete the earlier - and leave it in "Waiting for Screenshot" state and it will work immediately.
One more empirical data: NEVER use Upper case letter for the product ID even there is no any
error message or indication that you shouldn't.
This doc tells everything you need to know, but based on my several years practice the process is a "technical voodoo", and nobody could tell how and why it's working or not. Keep trying and somehow it works finally...

> **UPDATE 2015**
>   Apple fixed the process, now it's working even in
>   "Ready to Submit" phase
>   so you don't need to restart the process if accidentally the picture (named: Screenshot for Review) is uploaded, BUT all the other statements are valid.

Comment: "NEVER use Upper case letter for the product ID even there is no any error message or indication that you shouldn't" Thanks for the suggestion, but can you explain why not to do this (use uppercase letter) ?

Comment: @Whirlwind - it's just empirical as my experience, no real answer...could be a bug or anything else which is missing from the description of the api or documentation. Maybe it's fixed, you can try it and let us know here...

Comment: I have same question. I created product with screen shot and without screen shot too but still getting invalid product id

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) tutorial, it will work. As @mvds says, you must upload a binary (any binary) and then reject it. After that you will be able to use the sandbox environment as you want.

Comment: in this tutorial after reject binary wait after few hours for status change to invalid binary?

Comment: apparently sometimes yes, but i have never had to