# Do I have to submit an app to the appstore to check inapp purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to check inapp purchasesd for my game, but it says that for the first item, I need to submit an app for review, which is kind of silly, because the game isn't ready to publish yet, without checking inapp...

How can I test inapp purchases without really publishing it on the appstore?

Comment: I think YES... You need to submit it.. I posted an answer, you can check, might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42065967/3770366

Answer (score 2):

You can test it by creating sendbox user in itunes connect.
Please review this link : https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial
[image]

Comment: Already done that, but code says no valid items, so I can't even get to the signin dialog...

Comment: Just upload binary build and reject  it .Pease refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050605/ios-first-inapp-purchase-must-submit-binary-for-sandbox-testing

Comment: Thanks Hemant, that's what I did evantually. Will wait for a few days to get it approved.

Comment: So... that didn't work. my inapp was returned because there was no binary uploaded (uploaded and rejected)...

Comment: The error message is telling you that you cannot submit the IAP without a new binary.  The first time an app has IAPs submitted for approval the IAPs must be submitted with a new binary that handles those IAPs.

Comment: First, edit the IAP so they are no longer "Developer Action Needed".  Then upload the new binary but do not submit it.  Then attach the IAPs to the new binary.  Then submit the binary for approval.  This is described here:
 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH5-SW1

Comment: It may be that you already have IAPs approved for this app in which case you want to look here:
 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html
 
Which is the same place, just a little farther down the page.

Comment: Thing is, I want to test it before I submit for approval. once I submit it, it will be too late to find bugs in the purchase process...

This is my first IAP for this app.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your application on TestFlight (Apple product) with sandbox credentials,

**Steps to use test flight**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

**Steps to use sandbox**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

Comment: xcode console shows there are no valid items.
I think they have to be approved first...